# jQuery Select2 Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a form that allows a user to enter information. It uses the [select2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

On load, it is initiated to the visible form and works fine.

However, once I add a new div and run it again on all of the classes (original and added) it loses the values that were in the ones prior to adding a new one.

Is there a way to preserve this information when the plugin is run?

[image: Screenshot of website]

When you click on Add Vehicle, it inserts a new div and then runs the plugin again on the `.carpool` selector which is in each one of the divs.

```
$(".carpool").select2({
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    placeHolder: 'Agent Last name',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: { 
        url: "jsonUser.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        allowClear: true,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term, // search term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Is there a unique identifier on the `div` or the `select` that you could use to find only the new `select`?

Comment: Not currently but I suppose that's the only way to accomplish it

Comment: How are you "adding a new vehicle"? What does that look like?

Comment: I have the block/panel saved as a variable and when you click "Add Vehicle" it just appends it to the end of the div. It then runs a function that counts how many there are and numbers them accordingly. So if you have 6 blocks and remove the 3rd one, it will just recount and number them 1-5. In short, all its doing is copying or cloning the main div and then running the select2 function on the DOM using .carPool as the selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the plugin on the `div` you're adding. You have access to that specific `div`, because it's the one you're appending to the DOM. So if you have something like:

```
newDiv = $("<div>new stuff</div");
divContainer.append(newDiv);
newDiv.select2({...});
```

Clearly, you need to alter the above to fit the code you've got. If you need to run the plugin on some child elements of the new `div`, then you'd use something like:

```
newDiv.find("relevant child selector").select2({...});
```

Comment: I used a variation of this and got it working as expected. Thank you